# Цифры после формата фотографии

Tags: html

Зачем делать так:

> kreator-obraczek.jpg?1278516553

Я про цифры после формата.

Comment: Это `image.src + '?' + Math.random()`. Признак того, что уэб-разработчик не осилил заголовки, управляющие кэшированием.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы браузер думал, что это другая фотка и заново ее грузил, не из кэша.
Актуально бывает, например, для каптчи.
А вообще, есть много разных причин.
Одна из них - посмотреть откуда URL запрашивается, например, если несколько раз запросят картинку с одим номером, значит кидают на нее прямую ссылку, а надо заставить народ пройтись по сайту и посмотреть рекламу